# How to disable SSH Access & SFTP access but keep ftp access?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I don't know that much yet about servers so I am stuck right now, but I was wondering if its possible to disable SSH access & SFTP **for a certain user** but allow the ability to use FTP access and only access a certain directory.

If you have any questions please ask

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [manpage for the sshd configuration file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html).

The options you are looking for are `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups`, as well as their counterparts `DenyUsers` and `DenyGroups`.

If this configuration file is new to you, I strongly recommend you to checkout how to setup and configure the SSH service to use public keys, disable password logins and probably how to ban IP addresses that try to bruteforce passwords (like configuring fail2ban).

If you have a separate FTP service running on your server, it will not be affected.